# Query result with columns names

Tags: java, jdbc, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I'm using java, spring data jpa

Is there away to get as query result a map with column name and value?

```
something like: List<Map<String,object>> res = query.getResults();
```

EDIT:

I found [this](http://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/jdbc-statement-example-select-list-of-the-records/).

it uses JDBC statement.

```
        String queryString = "Select auditTime From AuditPlayer ap Where ap.id = 1"
        dbConnection = getDBConnection();
        statement = dbConnection.createStatement();
        // execute the SQL stetement
        rs = statement.executeQuery(queryString);
        rs.getString("auditTime")
```

this works, but is there a way to use * in the select:

```
Select * From AuditPlayer ap Where ap.id = 1
```

and now call a column name? `rs.getString("auditTime")

I keep getting error.

Answer (score 0):

You can return a map of column-name: column-value pairs using JdbcTemplate. Example:

```
public List<Map<String, Object>> getCustomers() {
    return this.jdbcTemplate.queryForList("SELECT customer_id, customer_name FROM customers");
}
```

This would return:

```
[{'customer_id': 4005, 'customer_name': 'John Smith'}, {...}, ... ]
```

Comment: Is it possible to get list of objects (as key value pair that contains <columnName, Value>) using JPA? I tried it using JPA but it returns List<Object[]>